# How do I get a selected list items value from a click event on a span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of items that I append a delete icon to like so:

```
$.each(data.files, function() {
    $('#listReports').append('<li><a href="#">'+ this + '</a><span class="del" style="float:right;"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span></li>');
});
```

CSS file:

```
li span.del {
  display: none;
}
li:hover span.del {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

JQuery Code:

```
$('li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('span.del').show();
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('span.del').hide();
    }
);
```

How can I select the list item value if a user clicks the del icon?

Comment: What do you mean by select? Did you mean to apply a blue background?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you add list items dynamically, and let's also assume that *list item value* is the text that `<a>` tag contains. If so, then the following code should do the job.

```
$("#listReports").on("click", ".del", function() {
    var value = $(this).siblings("a").text();
});
```

Comment: That did the trick, I was missing the siblings portion. Thanks!